# Elastic Search Not able to connect Remotely even after specifying HOST

Tags: elasticsearch, windows-server-2008-r2

I have specified the Network.host in elasticsearch.yml.

```
network.host: 192.168.x.x
```

Added host entry in the remote server C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

```
192.168.x.x domainname.com
```

I am not able to connect from remote server by accessing the below URL

http://domainname.com:9200/

Please suggest what else I should look into

Comment: Please provide an  output  from :
`iptables-save ` and  `netstat -lnpt ` on your 192.168.8.88  host.

Comment: what version of elasticsearch do you use?

Comment: Solved it by using reverse Proxy